# How to translate this query into find options?

Tags: typeorm

In this [documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options), I have an interesting example:

```js
userRepository.find({
    where: [
        { firstName: "Timber", lastName: "Saw" },
        { firstName: "Stan", lastName: "Lee" },
    ],
})
```

equals to

`SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE ("firstName" = 'Timber' AND "lastName" = 'Saw') OR ("firstName" = 'Stan' AND "lastName" = 'Lee')`

but how can i do the following:

`SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE ("firstName" = 'Timber' OR "lastName" = 'Saw') AND ("firstName" = 'Stan' OR "lastName" = 'Lee')`

I tried this:

```js
userRepository.find({
    where: {
        '':[{ firstName: "Timber"},{lastName: "Saw" }],
        '':[{ firstName: "Stan"}, {lastName: "Lee" }],
    },
})
```

but it didn't work